# Sonar - Method accesses list or array with constant index

Tags: java, sonarqube

Java Code:

```
List<ParsedUsuarioDto> parsedUsuarioDtos = new ArrayList<>(linhas.size());
for (String[] linha : linhas) {
    parsedUsuarioDtos.add(ParsedUsuarioDto.builder()
            .posicao(linhas.indexOf(linha) + 1)
            .cpf(linha[0])
            .rg(linha[1])
            .nome(linha[2])
            .mae(linha[3])
            .celular(linha[4])
            .email(linha[5])
            .dataNascimento(linha[6])
            .build());
}
```

Sonar gives me this message:

This method accesses an array or list using a constant integer index. Often, this is a typo where a loop variable is intended to be used. If however, specific list indices mean different specific things, then perhaps replacing the list with a first-class object with meaningful accessors would make the code less brittle.

How can i fix this bug?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is a bug (albeit a code smell). What SonarQube is suggesting instead of of having `String[] linha` have something like `Linha linha` which allows you to write `linha.getNome()` instead of `linha[2]`. A lot more readable and less likely to break when you start changing the order of elements in your array.

Also note that your loop has O(n²) complexity. It iterates the `linhas` array (O(n)), then for each element calls `indexOf` to find the position of the item (again O(n)). It's better to use an indexed for loop here (`for (int i = 0; i < linhas.length; ++i)`).

Your code would then become:

```
for (int i = 0; i < linhas.length; ++i) {
    final Linha linha : linhas[i];
    parsedUsuarioDtos.add(ParsedUsuarioDto.builder()
            .posicao(i + 1)
            .cpf(linha.getCpf())
            .rg(linha.getRg())
            .nome(linha.getNome())
            .mae(linha.getMae())
            .celular(linha.getCelular())
            .email(linha.getEmail())
            .dataNascimento(linha.getDataNascimento())
            .build());
}
```